# Are push notification tokens unique across all apps for a single device?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I will have multiple applications on the app store and 1 urban airship account to send push notifications to all of these devices.  What I want to know is if each Apple device has the same "push token" across all applications?  This is more of a database architecture thing so that I don't duplicate a push token many times if one single device uses many of my apps.

If each Apple device generates a unique push token for each application it has installed my architecture needs to change.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Device tokens are not exactly unique per device; they're unique per operating system installation. So if a user buys a new device but does not restore from backup, then they'll get a new device token. And if a device is wiped, it will get a new device token, so the new user doesn't get the old user's messages.

In addition, there are different tokens returned for development apps using the sandbox and distribution apps using the production system.

Since a single user might have your app installed on multiple devices legally (iPhone and iPad, for instance), it will be much safer to have a many to many relationship between users and device tokens, to be on the safe side.

And since you mentioned Urban Airship, you might find that our alias feature helps for this sort of thing; you can assign a non-unique alias to the different tokens in our end, and then we'll keep track of the mapping between your users and their device tokens. See the registration and push parts of the [UA documentation](http://docs.urbanairship.com/connect/connect_audience.html#aliases).

Edit: An update because I saw some more upvotes on this old answer. As of iOS 7, device tokens are unique for each application, even on the same device.

Comment: right now, i'm not doing "user accounts" such that one user will be "logged in" with multiple devices.  my system is set up such that each unique device ID is treated as an atomic entity (created or touched when they launch any of the apps) - any "many to many" that i'll need to do with soft user accounts can be implemented later. ----- excellent response, got everything i needed. urban airship is a great service, very happy to do business with you guys.

Comment: Will those old device tokens from the wiped devices show up in the Apple Feedback service?   And what happens if you try to send a notification to those now invalid tokens?

Comment: No, they won't show up in the feedback service. If you push to them, they do nothing.

Comment: If upgrade iOS from `10.3.0` to `10.3.1`, is device token expired ?

Answer (score 0):

According to apple latest doc:

> Never cache device tokens in your app; instead, get them from the system when you need them. APNs issues a new device token to your app when certain events happen. The device token is guaranteed to be different, for example, when a user restores a device from a backup, when the user installs your app on a new device, and when the user reinstalls the operating system. Fetching the token, rather than relying on a cache, ensures that you have the current device token needed for your provider to communicate with APNs. When you attempt to fetch a device token but it has not changed, the fetch method returns quickly.
>   [For more info check apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW3)